# how to pass parameters using api of https://kontakt.io/?

Tags: php, api, curl, kontakt.io

how to pass parameters using api of https://kontakt.io/?
[exsample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osCps.jpg)

https://developer.kontakt.io/api-reference/10/#tag/Device
How can I use this?

understand more than anything else how to pass all the parameters and the structure to use thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a body for post and query params for get methods.. Query are http://url/endpoint?param1=value1&param2=value2

Comment: Using what language?

Comment: Just download postman and try using that for starters to make the calls...